# Difference between int and System::Int32

Tags: .net, c++-cli, int, int32

As I'm writing applications using C++ .NET framework I want to ask a question.

When I am writing code exactly for "for loop" I always use this style of coding:

```
for( int i=0; i<somevalue; ++i ) {
    // Some code goes here.
}
```

but as I am using C++ .NET I can write

```
for( System::Int32 i=0; i<somevalue; ++i ) {
    // Some code goes here.
}
```

I think there are no difference Am I right ? If no can you explain whats the difference between this two ways and. witch one is more effective  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is probably being explicit about the range of values supported by `int` and `System::Int32`.

`System::Int32` makes the 32-bitness more explicit to those reading the code. One should use `int` where there is just need of 'an integer', and use `System::Int32` where the size is important (cryptographic code, structures) so readers will be clear of it while maintaining the same.

Using `int` or `System::Int32`the resulting code will be identical: the difference is purely one of explicit readability or code appearance.

Comment: @ViTo Brothers Apoyan: Have you read the modified answer? I don't think theres anything wrong.

Comment: @ViTo Brothers Apoyan: No difference at all.

Comment: I would consider `int` more portable and scalable than `System::Int32`. With later compiler versions and advances in hardware, the size of `int` could change for newer releases (requires recompiling) of the same code. If you specify `System::Int32`, it hard codes the size and range of that variable.

Answer (score 4):

The [C++/CLI language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-372.pdf) (p. 50) says that:

> The fundamental types map to
>   corresponding value class types
>   provided by the implementation, as
>   follows:
>
> - `signed char` maps to `System::SByte`.
> - `unsigned char` maps to `System::Byte`.
> - If a plain `char` is signed, `char` maps to `System::SByte`; otherwise, it
>     maps to `System::Byte`.
> - For all other fundamental types, the mapping is **implementation-defined** [emphasis mine].

This **differs** from C#, in which `int` is specifically defined as an alias for `System.Int32`.  In C++/CLI, as in ISO C++, an `int` has "the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment", and is only guaranteed to have at least 16 bits.

*In practice*, however, .NET does not run on 16-bit systems, so you can safely assume 32-bit `int`s.

But be careful with `long`: Visual C++ defines it as 32-bit, which is **not** the same as a C# long.  The C++ equivalent of `System::Int64` is `long long`.

Answer (score 1):

No.  One of them is just an alias for the other.

Comment: @ViTo: I'm not sure about C++/CLI, but I know that in C# `int` and `Int32` are exactly the same type: `int` is simply a language construct that means `System.Int32`.

Comment: Yes, it means they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

`int` in C# is the same as `System.Int32` of .Net.

Comment: But the question is NOT in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, unlike C and regular C++, C# and C++/CLI have an `int` type that is always 32 bits long.

This is confirmed by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), so the answer is that there is no difference between the two, other than the fact that `int` it considerably faster to type than `System::int32`.

Comment: If int is faster then System::Int32 I must always use int. And for what I need System::Int32 ?

Comment: You misunderstood me. `int` is shorter than `System::int32`, which means it takes less time to type. :) Other than that, they are just different names for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The two, `int` and `int32`, are indeed synonymous; `int` will be a little more familiar looking, `Int32` makes the 32-bitness more explicit to those reading your code.